# Install Grails mongodb plugin offline

Tags: mongodb, grails, plugins, offline

I need to install the Grails mongodb plugin in the environment with no Internet connection. I set up Grails 2.2.4. I am trying to install mongodb_1.3.0 plugin. What do I need to download on my local machine (or in my local Maven repository) to make the installation possible. I was trying to find for a file mongodb-1.3.0.zip, but could not file such file anywhere. The MongoDB plugin documentation is of no help about an offline installation of a plugin. It simply instructs you to add

compile ':mongodb:1.3.0' line to BuildCOnfig.groovy.

Comment: u have to run a mongod server, and then u can set up a connection from grails

Answer (score 0):

i think unless u downgrade your grails version to < 2.1 something ? there is no offline dependency resolving ,you also need to install the mongo dob plugin and uninstall hibernate using plugin manager `ALT+G`,M on windows .....